# Why am I receiving an ' Unable to retrieve card details from iATS. Error: Invalid Username or Password' Error?

Tags: civicontribute, iats

I'm using the following steps to produce this error:

1. Under the 'Contributions' tab of a contact on CiviCRM, click 'Recurring Contributions'

[image]

2. Click 'View' under the individual's recurring contribution

[image]

3. Clicking any of the following links (View, Edit, or Process)...

[image]

...results in the following error: 'Warning: Unable to retrieve card details from iATS. Error: Invalid Username or Password' (please see screenshot below)

[image: Error Message from iATS]

Donations seem to be processing fine on CiviCRM and iATS, and CiviCRM and iATS seem to be communicating fine with each other (other than this error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1) you have an iATS admin agent code 01 (and possibly more: 02, 03) and iATS agent codes 80, 81 and up for payment processing. Is it possible that the payment processor agent code/passwd that this particular contribution is linked to did have a password edit?

2) does your passwd for the agent code linked to that particular recurring series perhaps have any non-alphanumeric characters in it? Those are not recommended as we have seen them work in some cases but fail in others.